# Use .node file in vite

Tags: node.js, vite

I'm trying to use a local .node file in Vite.

Normally I can use require(), but in Vite I can only use import().

When im trying to import the file I get the error message:

"Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .node file format."

Is there a solution to use .node files in Vite?

Answer (score 1):

include this line in tsconfig.node.json

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```